# PhoneGap mobile applications

Tags: cordova

I just found PhoneGap and I want to use it for mobile applications,
is there an IDE for developing in PhoneGap?

thank you in advance.

Comment: Just about any Ruby IDE will do the job. Are you looking for an IDE that's geared specifically toward PhoneGap development? That might be a better question to ask.

Comment: Yes, but i don't have a lot of ideas for PhoneGap ? Thank you Brian

Answer (score 1):

You may use Eclipse! Or look at appMobi XDK (google it)

Comment: So, I can use Eclipse for Android applications and Xcode for iPhone, iPad, iPod applications ... ? or I can use appMobi XDK?, and programing for langage used: is HTML / JavaScript / CSS?

Comment: What I was saying was, you can use eclipse to develop phonegap application to run in Android. At the end you will have to "compile" the application into it's native form, so yes, you must have xcode for iphone. I know there are some online services where you upload the phonegap app and it will "compile" them into the native form, never used it... Good luck

Answer (score 1):

You can use eclipse with phonegap plugin. Install plugin to eclipse by this link

https://svn.codespot.com/a/eclipselabs.org/mobile-web-development-with-phonegap/tags/r1.2/download

and also read this [link](http://wiki.phonegap.com/w/page/34483744/PhoneGap%20Eclipse%20PlugIn%20for%20Android)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Adobe Dreamweaver CS6](http://phonegap.com/2012/04/24/adobe-dreamweaver-cs6-supports-phonegap-build/) for building up these mobile apps using [PhoneGap](http://phonegap.com/).

Or if you want to use different IDE's then -

For Android - Eclipse

For iOS - XCode

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [NSB/App Studio](http://www.nsbasic.com/app). The IDE has a feel similar to Visual Studio, and it lets you program in JavaScript and/or BASIC. It compiles directly to PhoneGap.

Answer (score 1):

NetBeans 7.4 supports PhoneGap development https://netbeans.org/community/releases/74/

Answer (score 0):

you can use *Dreamweaver CS 5.5* it allows you to to build a native mobile application using the popular *PhoneGap framework* - and deliver rich native applications to iOS and Android without needing to learn new languages or tools.

Answer (score 0):

Dreamweaver, Web matrix is good IDE
or Cloud9 IDE for cloud editor :D

Answer (score 0):

Actually NetBeans 7.4 supports Apache Cordova and not Phonegap. This way you can develop cross platform application without the need to install any additional plugin. YOu can read here the difference between Phonegap and Apache Cordova [phonegap.com](http://phonegap.com/2012/03/19/phonegap-cordova-and-what%E2%80%99s-in-a-name/)
I dont think that there is another IDE allowing it without adding any plugin.

Answer (score 0):

The [Monaca](http://monaca.mobi/en/) online IDE has saved me a lot of time and money. It works great and they integrate their beautiful UI (Onsen UI) with the projects. Moreover, they give you free server space to fetch and edit data online from your application! If your new I would highly recommend it as a place to start.

Answer (score 0):

Sublime text 3 , VS Code, Brakcet io , Web Storm , eclipse, visual studio,  web matrix, dream weaver, notepad plus

Comment: It would be helpful if you could list pros and cons of each and your experience using them.